# URL listed in applicationhost.config doesn't start in iis express

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, custom-domain

With the latest version of visual studio, when I start debugging my app, I don't have access to all the URLs I've set up in my `applicationhost.config` file. These were working up to about a week ago.

I have this in my applicationhost.config `bindings` section:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51415:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51415:subdomain.localhost" />            
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51415:othersubdomain.localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51415:thirdsubdomain.localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:pro.myPC.mydomain.biz" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:443:pro.myPC.mydomain.biz" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44303:pro.myPC.mydomain.biz" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44303:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

I only see some of those listed in IISExpress:

```
http://subdomain.localhost:51415/
http://thirdsubdomain.localhost:51415/
https://pro.myPC.mydomain.biz:44303/
https://localhost:44370/
```

***UPDATE:***
I removed the bindings for the subdomains, and http://localhost:51415 still doesn't work. Only the https url remains in the IIS Express system tray tool.

Comment: "I only see some of those listed in IISExpress". Do you refer to IIS Express system tray app? No document says how it works internally, so I assume this question cannot be easily answered without reverse engineering it.

Comment: Yes. And I can't navigate to them. This was working previously. Wish I knew what changed.

Comment: I find this surprisingly applicable to my specific situation... ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, I need to start Visual Studio as an Administrator. I had set my shortcut to always start as Admin, but apparently after the update, the shortcut was reset.

Starting as admin, this works.